# Jquery datatable warning

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable, datatables

I have a jquery editable table.
In code behind there are three actions.
One to load data for datatable 
Another to delete data from datatable 
And the last one for Save data.
There is nothing special in these actions.
I have The problem with save data. Data are saved correctly to database and then there is redirection to load data to datable again.
When data are saved correctly do database, there is redirection which load new data to datatable and then i get this warning:
DataTables warning: table id=myDataTable - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 8. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

I have looked this error on that page and i can not still find solution for this bug.
Interesting is when i get this error and i refresh page with datatable this time data are loaded correctly.
I do not know what is going on.
Please help

Here are two problematic actions

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult TesotwanieTabelki(int promotionId)
    {
        marketPromocji.Areas.DELIVER.Models.PromotionsProductsViewModel promotionProductsViewModelItem =
            new marketPromocji.Areas.DELIVER.Models.PromotionsProductsViewModel();

        promotionProductsViewModelItem.productDetails =
          new List<marketPromocji.Areas.DELIVER.Models.ProductDetails>();

        marketPromocji.Models.promocje promocje = unitOfWork.PromocjeRepository.GetByID(promotionId);
       aspnet_Users produktyWDanejPromocji=promocje.promocje_produkty.Select(x => x.produkty).First().aspnet_Users; //czyje produkty w danej promocji
       ICollection<produkty> produkty = unitOfWork.ProduktyRepository.Get().Where(x => x.aspnet_Users.UserId== produktyWDanejPromocji.UserId).ToList();

       List<SelectListItem> selectList=new List<SelectListItem>();

       foreach (produkty p in produkty)
       {
           selectList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = p.nazwa, Value = p.id.ToString()});
       }

       promotionProductsViewModelItem.selectList = selectList;

        promotionProductsViewModelItem.data_start = promocje.data_start;
        promotionProductsViewModelItem.data_koniec = promocje.data_koniec;
        promotionProductsViewModelItem.czy_zielony_koszyk = promocje.czy_zielony_koszyk;
        promotionProductsViewModelItem.id = promocje.id;
        promotionProductsViewModelItem.poziom_dostepnosci = promocje.poziom_dostepnosci;
        promotionProductsViewModelItem.wynagrodzenie = promocje.wynagrodzenie;
        if (promocje.sposob_wynagrodzenia != null)
        {
            promotionProductsViewModelItem.sposobWynagrodzenia = promocje.sposob_wynagrodzenia;
        }
        else
        {
            promotionProductsViewModelItem.sposobWynagrodzenia = "";
        }

        ICollection<marketPromocji.Models.promocje_produkty> promocje_produkty = unitOfWork.PromocjeProduktyRepository.Get().Where(x => x.ref_promocja == promotionId).ToList();

        foreach (marketPromocji.Models.promocje_produkty item in promocje_produkty)
        {
            promotionProductsViewModelItem.productDetails.Add(new marketPromocji.Areas.DELIVER.Models.ProductDetails()
            {
                productId = item.produkty.id,
                cena_brutto = item.cena_brutto,
                cena_brutto_dla_sklepu = item.cena_brutto_dla_sklepu,
                cena_netto = item.cena_netto,
                cena_netto_dla_sklepu = item.cena_netto_dla_sklepu,
                nazwa = item.produkty.nazwa,
                url_obrazka = item.produkty.url_obrazka
            });

        }

          Session[User.Identity.Name] = promotionProductsViewModelItem; //this session is used for datatable update action

        return View(promotionProductsViewModelItem);
    }

     [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult AddData(FormCollection formCollection)  
    {
        int promotionId = Convert.ToInt32(formCollection.Get("promotionId"));

        string addedProductId = formCollection.Get("Produkty");
        int productId = Convert.ToInt32(addedProductId);

        marketPromocji.Areas.DELIVER.Models.PromotionsProductsViewModel promotionsProductsViewModel = 
            (marketPromocji.Areas.DELIVER.Models.PromotionsProductsViewModel)Session[User.Identity.Name];

        produkty produkt = new produkty();

        produkt = unitOfWork.ProduktyRepository.GetByID(productId);

        promocje_produkty promocjeProdukty = new promocje_produkty();
        promocjeProdukty.cena_brutto = Convert.ToDecimal(formCollection.Get("cenaZakupuNetto"));            //tutaj to jeszcze musze sprawdzic czy to w odpowiedniej kolejnosci jest;/
        promocjeProdukty.cena_brutto_dla_sklepu = Convert.ToDecimal(formCollection.Get("cenaZakupuBrutto"));
        promocjeProdukty.cena_netto = Convert.ToDecimal(formCollection.Get("cenaSprzedazyNetto"));
        promocjeProdukty.cena_netto_dla_sklepu = Convert.ToDecimal(formCollection.Get("cenaSprzedazyBrutto"));

        string zielonyKoszyk = formCollection.Get("zielonyKoszyk");

        if(zielonyKoszyk==null)
        {
            promocjeProdukty.czy_zielony_koszyk = false;
        }
        else
        {
            promocjeProdukty.czy_zielony_koszyk = true;
        }
        promocjeProdukty.ref_produkt = productId;
        promocjeProdukty.ref_promocja = promotionId; 

        try
        {
            unitOfWork.PromocjeProduktyRepository.Insert(promocjeProdukty);

            unitOfWork.Save();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }

       return RedirectToAction("TesotwanieTabelki", new { promotionId=promotionId});
    }
```

Comment: We can't tell you what's wrong with your code if we can't see your code.

Comment: I have already found solution. Maybe it is not the best but work. After click send form i have destroyed datatable and reinitialized it again and worked